# "IF" function with "OR condition" always selecting first alternative

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
If B1>=(A1+1%)   OR   B1<=(A1-1%)
```

If either of this happens then display `Traditional`, otherwise `Modern`

I am using:

```
=IF(OR(B1>=(A1+1%), B1<=(A1-1%)), "TRADITIONAL", "MODERN")
```

But all the time it displays `Traditional`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the literal value that you expect it to show TRADITIONAL and likewise, what is the literal values of A1 and B1 that you expect the formula to show MODERN?

Answer (score 1):

What is effectively done here is:

- B1 >= (A1+1%): Is B1 1 percentile larger than A1 (or more)?
- B1 <= (A1-1%): Is B1 1 percentile smaller than A1 (or more)?

If either one of these are TRUE (because of OR), "TRADITIONAL" will be the result.

So, "MODERN" will only ever be output if B1 is equal to A1, or the difference between A1 and B1 is strictly less than 1 percentile. *e.g. ABS (A1-B1) < 1%*

So if A1 is 10%;

- If B1 is also 10%:
- **Result**: "MODERN"
- If B1 is greater than 11%
- **Result**: "TRADITIONAL"
- If B1 is less than 9%
- **Result**: "TRADITIONAL"
- If B1 is 11% or less AND B1 is 9% or greater
- **Result**: "MODERN"

So, it is working as intended. You could apply this to other contexts, like some important metric, so if a sudden change (>1% or <-1%) occurs, we could output "UNSTABLE", otherwise "STABLE".

So it is working properly, and:

> but all the time is displays Traditional

Is simply not true. The question is lacking details, so it can't be concluded what the expected results were, and what the expression was actually intended for. But there is confusion there for sure. Perhaps it was due to the data being used (wrong format)?

Answer (score 0):

You may be misunderstanding the effect of your formula.  Perhaps you want

```
=IF(OR(B1>=(A1*101%), B1<=(A1*99%)),"TRADITIONAL", "MODERN")
```